# Manifest file for Win16 app

Tags: winapi, 16-bit

Is it possible to enable Luna theme under Win XP or corresponding UI in Win7/10 using manifest file for Win16 application? For any Win32 executable using Common Controls library (COMCTL32), a detached manifest file with the same name will enable these UI extras. I need the same thing but for 16-bit app - if manifests are supported.

Comment: Not possible, there is no 16-bit uxtheme.dll.

Answer (score 1):

No. Manifest files are not supported for 16 bit processes, and 16 bit process have no support for XP themes.

Comment: Your answer is not entirely clear to me. Perhaps there is a missing negation somewhere?